# install virtualbox 6.1 on 19.10 with secure boot

Tags: virtualbox, secure-boot

I installed virtualbox 6.1 on a freshly installed ubuntu 19.10 with secure boot enabled. Even the kernel driver was installed with the MOK utility, asking me for a one time password. Yet I missed to enroll the drivers on reboot. After that the drivers where obviously not loaded.

I tried reinstalling virtual box 
`apt remove --purge virtualbox-6.1` and then `apt install virtualbox-6.1` (and other variants) but the MOK driver signing never came up again. Also `vboxsetup` is not signing the drivers and asking to do it manually (this has already been answered).

How can I re-enroll the driver signing for virtualbox by the new virtualbox / ubuntu (that already worked) solution?

Comment: What is "mint ubuntu 19.10"?

Comment: with mint ubuntu I mean: just recently installed from scratch, no inplace upgrades that sometimes leave behind residues, that might mess with this kind of stuff.

Comment: So what did you install? Mint or Ubuntu?

Comment: ubuntu (straight no flavor).